# no such element found exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver

here one edit option is there, i need to find that edit element..but in console i didn't get any exception..element is not clicking in Web page..

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\UMASHANKAR\\Documents\\selenuim\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();


//login to an application
  driver.get("https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/dashboard");
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("admin@malbork.in");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("NsSaNj@0205");
    driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();

//for edit page
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Driver Management')]")).click();

//edit element 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'updateDriver')]"));
```

Comment: anybody help me

Comment: if i use WebDriverwait also,same issue i m facing..

Comment: anybody is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change resolution this `driver.manage().window().maximize();` to this `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920,1080));`

Comment: `//for edit page
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Driver Management')]")).click();
        try {
  WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@href,'updateDriver')]"));
   String editDriverUrl = el.getAttribute("href");
   driver.get(editDriverUrl);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }`
but this will get you to the first row of a table

Comment: `//for edit page
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Driver Management')]")).click();
  try {
   List<WebElement> el = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@href,'updateDriver')]"));
    int i = 0; // num of element which you want to access 
    String editDriverUrl = el.get(i).getAttribute("href");
    driver.get(editDriverUrl);

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }`